# Google keeps crawling old site, ignores new (& better) one

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, web-crawlers

Searching 'Dragon Notes' in Google predominantly yields **(1)** rather than **(2)** - even for images; **(2)**'s almost non-existent. Differences:

- **(2)** is more up-to-date, has a better sitemap and source code
- **(2)** was submitted as an *exact copy of **(1)*** - and only improved from thereon
- **(2)** takes a lot longer than **(1)** did to 'Validate' new pages
- **(2)**'s average (search) 'Position' is 74 (Google analytics) - **(1)**'s was significantly lesser
- **(1)** is removed from 'Properties' in Google Search Console, leaving only **(2)**
- **(1)**, however, isn't deleted from its hosting provider (or simply 'deleted')

I no longer update **(1)**, and don't wish it in search results; I've only kept it out of concern that neither of my sites will show on search, rather than the less-desired one (is this true?).

Any remedy? Help's appreciated.

**(1)**: https://dragonnoteshq.com 
**(2)**: https://dragonnotes.org

Answer (score 3):

To pass the link juice, did you do a 301 Permanent Redirect from you **(1)** to **(2)**?

If YES, then wait for more time to let google recognize the new site.

IF NO, then do the above suggested step.

Comment: Facing bit of a roadblock @301PR; in the meantime - would deleting **(1)** be as or more effective than a 301?

Comment: If deleting **(1)** would not have any impact on your revenue goals and have the time to wait for your new one to rank, then YES. If your **(1)** has been ranking earlier and driving high traffic to your site, then it is a NO.

Comment: This is a bit risky and I would recommend to do cautiously. Above is a suggestion based on my personal experience. While I did the above, some URLs took 24 hours to regain positions while others took 15-30 days to rank due to high competition. Also, some never regained their rankings and are still stuck in 2nd or 3rd page.

Answer (score 0):

Yours site **1** is killing/cannibalising the site **2**. Since the older version has more authority over the second one, **1** will beat **2** in rankings for a long time.
to-do;
Map all your older URLs to new ones and implement a 301 redirect at a page level.

- a) List all your Site 1 URLs in a single column in excel
- b) List all your Site 2 URLs in a single column next to in excel
- c) Map all those URLs to each other
- d) Using this mapping sheet, create 301 redirects for URL to URL and implement this to site 1.

Result: In time, site 1 will disappear from SERPs and site 2 will start showing up..

Comment: Facing bit of a roadblock @301PR; in the meantime - would deleting (1) be as or more effective than a 301?

Comment: It will work but, not as efficient and fast as 301 redirects.
Plus: site1 authority will go down the sinkhole.. so site2 will not be able to benefit from it.. And also; your users (searchers) will see 404 pages for along time..